# bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke Incorrect context when called using the bpy module in headless mode

Tags: python, sculpting

I have been trying to sculpt a mesh using the Python API (v2.83), running via the `bpy` module in headless mode. So far, I can render the mesh as is, but as soon as I try to use `bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke()` I get the RunTimeError:

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke.poll() failed, context is incorrect

The following are the contents of my `bpy.context`:

[image: contents of bpy.context]

Note that I have set the mode to "SCULPT", and would like to sculpt the "Body" object. Inspecting the contents of `bpy.context.area`, it is `None`. Should it be "3D_VIEW", and how to change it since `bpy.context.area` is read only?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See: [poll() failed, context incorrect?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)

Comment: There is no UI in headless mode. This is why area, space_data, region are none. If the operator needs a UI element to poll, then AFAIK there is no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

bpy.context holds some information about the current windows and open views which is needed by bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke and not available in headless mode. Take a look at this example [here](https://github.com/christian-vorhemus/procedural-3d-image-generation/blob/master/blenderBackgroundTask.py#L71) to see how to use brush_stroke() without headless mode. If you use Blender on a machine which doesn't have a graphical user interface, you could use a virtual frame buffer (see [here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender2-82-xvfb-virtual-screen-rendering-with-strange-texture-results-eevee/12750)).